# On adding terms to limits

Tags: calculus

Is it always possible to add terms into limits, like in the following example? (Or must certain conditions be fulfilled first, such as for example the numerator by itself must converge etc)

$\lim_{h \to 0} {f(x)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}$

Comment: The fact that is a limit is not important. What is happening is that $a/b=ac/bc$, as long as $c\neq0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what "add terms into limits" is supposed to mean in general.  In your example, you're not really doing anything: $f(x)$ and $\dfrac{e^x f(x)}{e^x}$ are equal, so any well-defined operation on them produces the same results.

Comment: I meant putting in new terms although they cancel out. I was worried that with those new terms, the L'Hopital's Rule might give weird results, because those new terms start getting differentiated and more new terms come out.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule is a *test* you can sometimes apply to find whether there is a limit and if so what it is. Your question about L'Hospital's rule is like asking whether you can cause the car to run out of oil by throwing away the dipstick. The dipstick is for *testing* the oil level. Perhaps you can't test the oil level if you throw away the dipstick, or perhaps you know another way to test, but either way the car still has an oil level and the oil level is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f,g$ are defined on the punctured neighbourhood of point $a$ and limits $$\lim_{x \to a} {f(x)},\quad \lim_{x \to a} {g(x)}$$exist.
Then $\lim_{x \to a} {f(x)\cdot g(x)}$ exists and
$$\lim_{x \to a} {f(x)\cdot g(x)}=\lim_{x \to a} {f(x)}\cdot \lim_{x \to a} {g(x)}$$